# How to create decentralized reference for File.stream?

Tags: elixir

Its common that after creating a stream, people will run the stream to start streaming! sounds direct.

Like:

```
File.stream!(path)
|> Stream.run
```

But, how can I postpone running the stream until I need to run it? The only way I can see is to register the stream in a decentralized reference, and use the reference later to run the stream.

Is this even possible? how?

**EDIT**
Here is what I am trying to do:
[image]

Comment: You mean you want the to delay yielding the first (or any) item of a Stream for an arbitrary duration?

Comment: No, I want to be able to trigger it via its reference only when I need, something like in the diagram above..

Comment: How about creating a GenServer which stores map of key -> stream in its state, a `call` to store a stream with key, and a `call` which takes a key and starts running that stream in a new process and also removes it from the state?

Comment: But I even don't know how to store the stream into a map of key->value? Also, is the `GenServer` the only way to persist a state? ex: map of keys. ?

Comment: You can use an ETS table as well.

Comment: With those options handy, how can I create a decentralized reference for a stream? like the one created at question above?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the diagram completely, but you can always generate a random unique id, e.g. UUID, send that to the user and store the stream with that id as the key in the GenServer.

Comment: But how to store the stream it self, is it as simple as: stream= File.stream!(path) ? sorry as it seems a dump question..

Comment: @simo in a `GenServer` (you might make use of [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html) for that) you might “store” whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to store streams and run them later using a GenServer:

```
defmodule StreamStore do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
  end

  def init(_) do
    {:ok, %{map: %{}, next: 0}}
  end

  def put(server, stream) do
    GenServer.call(server, {:store, stream})
  end

  def run(server, key) do
    GenServer.call(server, {:run, key})
  end

  def handle_call({:store, stream}, _from, %{map: map, next: next}) do
    state = %{map: Map.put(map, next, stream), next: next + 1}
    {:reply, next, state}
  end

  def handle_call({:run, key}, _from, %{map: map} = state) do
    # If the key exists, pop and run it, otherwise return `{:error, :badkey}`.
    case Map.pop(map, key) do
      {nil, _} ->
        {:reply, {:error, :badkey}, state}
      {stream, map} ->
        Task.start_link(Stream, :run, [stream])
        {:reply, :ok, %{state | map: map}}
    end
  end
end

{:ok, ss} = StreamStore.start_link

# I'm storing a `Stream.map` over a list here, but you can store file streams as well.
first = StreamStore.put(ss, [1, 2, 3] |> Stream.map(&IO.puts/1))
second = StreamStore.put(ss, [4, 5, 6] |> Stream.map(&IO.puts/1))
third = StreamStore.put(ss, [7, 8, 9] |> Stream.map(&IO.puts/1))

Process.sleep(100)
IO.inspect StreamStore.run(ss, second)
Process.sleep(100)
IO.inspect StreamStore.run(ss, third)
Process.sleep(100)
IO.inspect StreamStore.run(ss, first)
Process.sleep(100)
# The stream has been removed from the store, so this will print `{:error, :badkey}`
IO.inspect StreamStore.run(ss, first)
```

Output:

```
:ok
4
5
6
:ok
7
8
9
:ok
1
2
3
{:error, :badkey}
```

`StreamStore.put/2` returns a key which can later be passed to `StreamStore.run/2` to run that particular stream. I'm using `Task.start_link` to spawn a process and run the stream in that. You'll probably want to adjust all that before using it, but this should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

`File.Stream!` returns a value that you can store and run as many times as you want. Streams are implemented in Elixir as the composition of functions. Something like this.

```
 stream_maps = Map.put(%{}, client_tag, File.Stream!(path) )
```

Sometime later,

```
 stream_maps |> Map.get(client_tag) |> Stream.run
```

You can extend this to any composition of Stream functions from the original File.Stream!.

Comment: thanks, but I need a way to store stream_maps to use it even later

Comment: by using a reference, a string maybe? That's what I am looking for